# Is it possible to port Flashdevelop project from Openfl to Android?

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop, neko

I made a neko project for Windows using FlashDevelop. I want to see if I can port it for android without remaking code or too much of it. In the past I was able to port to hmtl5 without having to remake code. Of course making an APK is different and requires getting some packages installed, I know that. The question is can I build android or I have to start a new project (like AS3) and go on in its own way?

I setup the 
Path to Android SDK [C:\Programs\Android Development\platform-tools]: (contains adb, other files and the build-tools folder)
Path to Android NDK [C:\Programs\Android Development\android-ndk-r20]:
Path to Java JDK [C:\Programs\Android Development\jdk1.8.0_221]:

A simple project that displays an image. Errors I get when building 'android'

> ‘arm-linux-androideabi-g++’ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Error: Could not create PCH
>   Build halted with errors.

Or
in NativeCFFI.hx error: function body required
@:cffi private static function lime_jni_create_method(className:String, method:String, signature:String, isStatic:Bool, quiet:Bool):Dynamic;

Answer (score 2):

> ‘arm-linux-androideabi-g++’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Error: Could not create PCH Build halted with errors.

That error comes from an Android NDK that is too recent. Current HXCPP releases only support versions up to **r15c**, so I suggest you downgrade to that version.

Alternatively, you could try installing HXCPP from GitHub, as support for newer NDKs was [recently merged](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/pull/825).

Comment: yes thanks that removed the arm- error, by going to older NDK. It failed now with this:
**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: C:\Programs\Android Development\platform-tools
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.**

I don't have android-26 folder, I even have android-10 folder renamed to build-tools. Is such build even possible? Or better go AS3?

Comment: So far I've yet to see success with making android build from a simple openfl. And can I get some proper guide, in FlashDevelop it asks for android-26 folder, build-tools, platform tools, downloaded all separate, how do I make a proper SDK folder where all is present and found?